# python dictionary sum and average by year

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, sum, average

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
import datetime
test={datetime.date(1977, 6, 5): [81, 55, 0.0, False],
 datetime.date(2007, 11, 18): [45, 41, 0.02, True],
 datetime.date(2017, 11, 3): [43, 33, 0.3, True],
 datetime.date(2007, 2, 24): [44, 36, 0.36, True],
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 18): [54, 40, 0.0, False],
 datetime.date(2008, 11, 18): [51, 43, 0.01, True],
 datetime.date(1965, 12, 29): [43, 33, 0.27, True]}

sumtmax=0
year=[]
for k, v in test.items():
    year.append(k.year)
yearset=set(year)
print(yearset)

for i in yearset:
    for k, v in test.items():
        k=k.year
        if k==i:
            print(v[0])
```

I want to get the average of value[0] and the sum of value[3] for each year. How should I do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you results in form of dict without external libraries:

```
sum3 = {}

for k, v in test.items():
    sum3[k.year] = sum3.get(k.year, 0) + v[3]

avg0 = {}

for k, v in test.items():
    value = avg0.get(k.year, (0, 0))
    avg0[k.year] = (value[0] + v[0], value[1] + 1.0)

avg0 = {k: v[0]/v[1] for k, v in avg0.items()}

sum3
#{2017: 1, 1965: 1, 2007: 2, 2008: 1, 1977: 0, 2015: 0}
avg0
#{2017: 43.0, 1965: 43.0, 2007: 44.5, 2008: 51.0, 1977: 81.0, 2015: 54.0}
```

Comment: hi, zipa,can you explain this part: for k, v in test.items():
    value = avg0.get(k.year, (0, 0))
    avg0[k.year] = (value[0] + v[0], value[1] + 1.0)

Comment: @KarenJiang You seem to understand the `get()` concept, so I'm just changing the default value to `(0, 0)` tuple as a starting point and adding new value to it as well as increasing counter by one. The `1.0` part is for the `2.x` users, otherwise you can user `1` in python `3.x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with this kind of data I would definitely suggest to use a table representation using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(test).T.astype(float)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')

avg0 = df.groupby(df.index.year)[0].mean()

Out[60]: 
1965    43.0
1977    81.0
2007    44.5
2008    51.0
2015    54.0
2017    43.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64

sum3 = df.groupby(df.index.year)[3].sum()

sum3
Out[61]: 
1965    1.0
1977    0.0
2007    2.0
2008    1.0
2015    0.0
2017    1.0
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Comment: not average and sum of all together, I want the result for each year....

Answer (score 1):

You can use python builtin [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to get sum of value by year, to get average just divide the sum by the number of entry by year:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
import datetime


test = {
   datetime.date(1977, 6, 5): [81, 55, 0.0, False],
   datetime.date(2007, 11, 18): [45, 41, 0.02, True],
   datetime.date(2017, 11, 3): [43, 33, 0.3, True],
   datetime.date(2007, 2, 24): [44, 36, 0.36, True],
   datetime.date(2015, 2, 18): [54, 40, 0.0, False],
   datetime.date(2008, 11, 18): [51, 43, 0.01, True],
   datetime.date(1965, 12, 29): [43, 33, 0.27, True]
}

yearset = set([k.year for k in test.keys()])

for i in yearset:
    print(sum([v[0] for k, v in test.items() if k.year == i]) / len(list(filter(lambda x: x.year == i, test.keys()))))
    print(sum([v[3] for k, v in test.items() if k.year == i]))
```

Comment: why not `year = set()` and `year.add()` ?